# Google Drive API - Search doesn't work unless I specify exact folder

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Google Drive API works very oddly...

When I do a query `name contains 'ZL210109'` then it finds nothing, I also tried `fullText` etc.

However when I query `'1-x_O040L9K1wT6vKKGqeRUvZEe2ql7yq' in parents and name contains 'ZL210109'` then it will find the results!

In this case however Google only searches the given folder and not its subfolders! I only know the ID of the root folder and it has so many subfolders that it takes forever to recursively go through them and find all the Ids. So basically the search is useless.

Can someone explain/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, wow...

**I had to add these parameters (driveId, corpora, supportsAllDrives) and now the search works without the need of specifying the parents folder!**

At some point it was also showing `"The driveId parameter must be specified if and only if corpora is set to drive."`

```
    $optParams = array(
        'supportsAllDrives' => true,
        'corpora' => 'drive',
        'pageSize' => 100,
        'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
        'fields' => 'files(id, name, mimeType, size)',
        'q' => 'name contains 'ZL210109',
        'driveId' => '0zxtOkG3ucfeRUk9PVA',
    );
    
    $ret = [];
    $nextPageToken = null;
    do {
        $results = $this->service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```